# Relations between an integral in $\Omega$ and in $\partial \Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is there some inequality which relates

$$\int_{\Omega}|f|^{2}\textrm{ and 
} \int_{\partial\Omega}|f|^{2}$$ for some $f \in L^{2}(\Omega) \cap L^{2}(\partial \Omega)$?

Comment: Idea: If we had weak differentiability and then use stokes theorem, it suffices to find an inequality between the derivative of $f$ and $f$ itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk in $\mathbf R^2$.  The function $f(x,y) = (1-x^2 - y^2)^{1/2}$ satisfies $$\int_\Omega |f|^2  = \frac \pi 2 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\partial \Omega} |f|^2  = 0.$$

On the other hand the functions $f_n(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)^{n/2}$ satisfy
$$\int_\Omega |f_n|^2  = \frac \pi{n+1} \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\partial \Omega} |f_n|^2  = 2 \pi$$ so that in general the ratio $$ \frac{ \int_\Omega |f|^2 }{\int_{\partial \Omega} |f|^2}$$ is bounded neither above nor below.